# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field zzakj of type Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult

Tags: google-signin

I follow the steps in the google developers, and I can run the sign-in demo.

1. Add the dependency to your project-level build.gradle

   ```
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
   ```
2. Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```

In your app-level build.gradle file, declare Google Play Services as a dependency:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
}
```

Here's my project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here's my app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.kdapp.partygor"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
       //signingConfig signingConfigs.cic
        renderscriptDebuggable false
    }
debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
        renderscriptDebuggable true
       //signingConfig signingConfigs.cic
        minifyEnabled true
    }
  }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // 日曆視圖自定義 view
    // 雙向 seekBar
    // 輪播圖
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.ashokvarma.android:bottom-navigation-bar:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.zhy:okhttputils:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
    compile 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.youth.banner:banner:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    // Dependency for Google Sign-In
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':redpacketlibrary')
    compile project(':easeui')
    compile project(path: ':pickerview')
    compile files('libs/parse-android-1.13.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-multidex.jar')

  }


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But when I  run my project, I get this error.

```
08-04 09:34:45.420 22456-22456/net.kdapp.partygor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: net.kdapp.partygor, PID: 22456
                                                                java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field zzazX of type Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult' appears in /data/data/net.kdapp.partygor/files/instant-run/dex/slice-google-play-services_78c2c5fe145c1c95c9696f0679d986433b0c2b89-classes.dex)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzo.zzrj(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzs(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzrk(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5877)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1019)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:814)
```

I search in google many times and change the google-services api version, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I think you have 2 layouts with the same name

Comment: I found out the problem is my phone not install Google Play services.